# How to define this Laravel relationship

Tags: php, database, laravel

Hello I do have a ER diagram like below. I am thinking this is a hasmanyThrough relationship but I am not sure:

[image]

Any ideas how to define migrations and relationships for those tables ?

Answer (score 1):

in User::class
you can use the relation

```
public function organizations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Organization::class ,
        'organization_user',
        'user_id', //user key on intermediate table
        'organization_id' //organization key on intermediate table
    );
}

public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Role::class ,
        'organization_user',
        'user_id', //user key on intermediate table
        'role_id' //role key on intermediate table
    );
}
```

more info on [laravel many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: How do I access from organiations ?